# Can I get a path for a Memory Mapped File? (.NET 4.0)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, memory-mapped-files

I want that a non-.NET application access a Memory Mapped file, **but this application is not aware of the existence of Memory Mapped files**, so I need the file path. It is possible?

Comment: Good question... unfortunately, it seems the answer is no.

Answer (score 3):

They have some samples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx).

**EDIT**

I think [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366878%28VS.85%29.aspx) would provide the answer. Basically, it would seem some sort of memory pointer is required for memory-mapped files, and not a file system path.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [GetMappedFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683195(v=vs.85).aspx) function to get the path to a memory mapped file when it is mapped. This of course requires that the memory mapped file is actually backed by a physical file, but the question makes it vague what the situation exactly is. Did some third party library hand you a MemoryMappedFile, MemoryMappedViewAccessor or MemoryMappedViewStream, but you don't know whether it is backed by a physical file?

Here is a sample showing how one would get the filename from a MemoryMappedFile:

```
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace MMFilePathTest
{
    static class Program
    {
        private static MemoryMappedFile GetMappedPhysicalFile()
        {
            return MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile("test.bin", System.IO.FileMode.Create, null, 4096);
        }

        private static MemoryMappedFile GetMappedAnonymousMemory()
        {
            /* The documentation errounously claims that mapName must not be null. Actually anonymous
             * mappings are quite a normal thing on Windows, and is actually both safer and more secure
             * if you don't have a need for a name for them anyways.
             * (Reported as https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/5404)
             * Using a name here gives the exact same results (assuming the name isn't already in use). */
            return MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew(null, 4096);
        }

        /* This can be changed to kernel32.dll / K32GetMappedFileNameW if compatibility with Windows Server 2008 and
         * earlier is not needed, but it is not clear what the gain of doing so is, see the remarks about
         * PSAPI_VERSION at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683195(v=vs.85).aspx */
        [DllImport("Psapi.dll", EntryPoint = "GetMappedFileNameW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int GetMappedFileName(
          SafeProcessHandle hProcess,
          SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle lpv,
          [Out] StringBuilder lpFilename,
          int nSize
        );

        /* Note that the SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle property of SafeMemoryMappedViewAccess and SafeMemoryMappedViewStream
         * is actually the address where the file is mapped */
        private static string GetPathWithGetMappedFileName(SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle memoryMappedViewHandle)
        {
            // The maximum path length in the NT kernel is 32,767 - memory is cheap nowadays so its not a problem 
            // to just allocate the maximum size of 32KB right away.
            StringBuilder filename = new StringBuilder(short.MaxValue);
            int len;
            len = GetMappedFileName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().SafeHandle, memoryMappedViewHandle, filename, short.MaxValue);
            if (len == 0)
                throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            filename.Length = len;
            return filename.ToString();
        }

        private static void PrintFileName(MemoryMappedFile memoryMappedFile)
        {
            try
            {
                using (memoryMappedFile)
                using (MemoryMappedViewAccessor va = memoryMappedFile.CreateViewAccessor())
                {
                    string filename = GetPathWithGetMappedFileName(va.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle);
                    Console.WriteLine(filename);
                }
            }
            catch (Win32Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: 0x{0:X08}: {1}", e.NativeErrorCode, e.Message);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PrintFileName(GetMappedPhysicalFile());
            PrintFileName(GetMappedAnonymousMemory());
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this I get the output:

```
\Device\HarddiskVolume5\Users\poizan\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MMFilePathTest\MMFilePathTest\bin\Debug\test.bin
Error: 0x000003EE: The volume for a file has been externally altered so that the opened file is no longer valid
```

Note that the path is returned in native NT path format. If you need to convert that into a dos/win32 format, see this question: [How can I convert a native (NT) pathname into a Win32 path name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445108/how-can-i-convert-a-native-nt-pathname-into-a-win32-path-name)

For the error when there is not file associated, the error message is a bit weird, but the error code means [ERROR_FILE_INVALID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc231199.aspx), which makes sense since there is no file.