# WindowsAPI GetDeviceDriverFileName( ) is not giving the full path

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I am trying to get the list of paths of all the device drivers loaded currently on my Windows PC.

In two ways I tackled the situation:

1. I first tried, using `EnumDeviceDrivers( )` with `GetDeviceDriverFileName( )`.
2. Next I tried, `EnumServicesStatus( )` with `QueryServiceConfig( )`

Both are giving me the path name of device drivers. First one is giving the path name in fully qualified form whereas the latter is giving the path name which contains some environment variables

[image]

Using the first one is kind of tedious whereas the second function is easy to use. That's why I want to know if there is any function available by which I can perform the task easily and get the full qualified path name ( eg: C:\Windows\System32\.........)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445108/how-can-i-convert-a-native-nt-pathname-into-a-win32-path-name

Comment: Those aren't environment variables. They are symlinks in the [NT namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#nt-namespaces). The Q&A posted by @HansPassant is thus the right question to ask.